# Can I use attr() inside background url() in CSS?

Tags: css, background-image, attr

I would like to do this in HTML:
   `<a href="http://host.com/cat.png">text</a>`

and in CSS:
`a {
      background-image: url(attr(href));
    }`

It doesn't seem to work for me. Is it even possible?

Comment: Are you using jquery at all in your site?

Comment: I'm just investigating for academic purposes. I'm trying to see if it can be achieved using pure CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible in static CSS file. However you can have dynamically generated CSS by any server side language such as PHP.

Or use [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) if you need variables in CSS.